# How to configure spring boot to set hibernate's config using application.properties

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I've been following this [tutorial](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/) to implement Hibernate into my application. However, I do not know how to read the application.properties mentioned in it. I've read the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) too, it is mentioned :

- A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
- The current directory
- A classpath /config package
- The classpath root

But what's the current directory with spring boot?

I am also *not* using the following dependencies (cf tutorial), could my problem be solved by using them ? It is causing a dependencies clash :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

Also, simply putting applications.properties in src/main/resources as detailed in the tutorial doesn't work.
It does work if I manually set the following (this is what I use with Spring Security) :

```
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
      DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate");
      driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
      driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("root");
      return driverManagerDataSource;
  }
```

But if I remove the previous code, it definitely doesn't find applications.properties :

`Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans`

Would anyone know how to solve this problem, or have a lead ? Thanks!

Edit :

So a little bit more explanations on what I've done. Here's the architecture of my project : [http://imgur.com/a/V3f7p](https://imgur.com/a/V3f7p)

As I said, my pom is different, here is it : http://pastebin.com/fjrfKcVX

I have a WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, which shouldn't interfere with anything :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean(name = "simpleMappingExceptionResolver")
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver createSimpleMappingExceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver r = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties mappings = new Properties();
       mappings.setProperty("ClassNotFoundException", "greeting");
       mappings.setProperty("SQLException", "greeting");
       mappings.setProperty("IOException", "greeting");

        r.setExceptionMappings(mappings); // None by default
        r.setDefaultErrorView("error"); // No default
        r.setExceptionAttribute("ex"); // Default is "exception"
        r.setWarnLogCategory("example.MvcLogger"); // No default
        return r;
    }

      @Override
        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
         /*   registry.addViewController("/accueil").setViewName("accueil");
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("accueil");
            registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
            registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");*/
          registry.addViewController("/accessdenied").setViewName("accessdenied");
        }

    /*  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
      public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
          DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
          driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ai_15");
          driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
          driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("root");
          return driverManagerDataSource;
      }*/


}
```

Aside from that, it is identical and nothing is interfering with Hibernate. I've just renamed everything as 'Test', such as **TestDAO.java**.

Edit 2 : my *application.properties* file is identical to the one in the tutorial, except the following line :

`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate`

Comment: "simply putting applications.properties in src/main/resources as detailed in the tutorial doesn't work." Isn't helping. The tutorial works so you should explain what you've done so that we understand what went wrong.

Comment: I've edited my question to add more infos. To summarize the main differences are my `WebSecurityConfig` and my pom.xml.

Comment: The edit doesn't help I am afraid. You're stating that you've used "application.properties" as detailed in the tutorial but that doesn't work. We still don't know what you've put in application.properties. You can also run your app in debug mode (`--debug`) to get the auto-configuration report: this should tell you why the `DataSource` wasn't configured.

Comment: I used the same application.properties, except that I changed the `spring.datasource.url` to adapt it to my db. I'm gonna see how I can enable the debug mode with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to specify your property file in database config xml.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
```

jdbc.properties is the name of the property file placed under resources. then you can access the properties like below :

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"  destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="entityInterceptor"/>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${jdbc.showsql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${jdbc.schema}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note : all my property name start with jdbc. so that is why those are referred as jdbc.name

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where is the config.xml ? I can't find it anywhere in my project.

Comment: Ohkay, you are using annotations. Is your property file exactly same as shown in the tutorial you have mentioned ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same, except that I changed `spring.datasource.url` to point to my db.